# The value of a local variable of a function has to be retained over multiple calls to the function. How should that variable be declared in PHP

Tags: php

The value of a local variable of a function has to be retained over multiple calls to the function. How should that variable be declared in PHP?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

using `static`. example:

```
function staticDemo() {
  static $x =1;
  echo $x;
  $x++;
}
```

the variable `$x` gets that static value the first time the function is called, afterwards it retains it's state.

example:

```
staticDemo(); // prints 1
staticDemo(); // prints 2
staticDemo(); // prints 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Just FYI:

```
   function globalDemo() {
       global $x;
       echo $x;
       $x++;
   }

   globalDemo(); // prints ''
   globalDemo(); // prints 1
   globalDemo(); // prints 2
   globalDemo(); // prints 3
```